# JdbcTemplate should only make connections when a method of that is called

Tags: spring, datasource, jdbctemplate

```
    final String sql = someSql;
    try {
        if (location1 == location) {

            return jdbcTemplateLocation1.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
// Some Code
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return list.size();
                }
            });
        } else {
            return jdbcTemplateLocation2.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

                @Override
                public void setValues(final PreparedStatement paramPreparedStatement, final int paramInt) throws SQLException {
// some code
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return dtoList.size();
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        // Log exception
    }
```

We have a situation in which one location1 is going down for maintenance for 2 days and whenever the call is made to location2, it tries to make connection to location1 as well whether its called or not getting time outs and connection timeout logs. Is there a way through which can make the jdbcTemplate to make connections only when one of its method is called without commenting any code. Any help would be much appreciated.

Xml Bean configurations are as below :

```
<alias name="dataSourceLocation1" alias="dataSourceLocation1" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${maxConnections}" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="${maxIdle}" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="${connectionTimeoutInMs}" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    <property name="validationQuery">
        <value>${validationQuery}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="testOnBorrow">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>

</bean>

<alias name="jdbcTemplateLocation1" alias="jdbcTemplateLocation1" />
<bean id="jdbcTemplateLocation1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceLocation1" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried using lazy-init="true" on the beans you don't want to initialize immediately when your spring container is boot-strapped? You would have to use this property on the dataSource bean. The problem with this approach of course is that if you have mis-configured something, then you won't find out until late in your application's runtime. Alternatively I am guessing a possibility here is to use a connection pool rather than BasicDataSource, there could be customizations to avoid hard failures when starting the container.

Comment: Hi @Kristoffer, Yes, I have tried using lazy-init="true" but the problem in this case is that when the call comes for location2, it still tries to make connection for location1 and causing timeouts and unnecessary logs.